Qt: how to calculate image coordinates on label?
I am writing an app, that displays an image and allows the User to interact with the image using mouse. The image size is predefined, and in the code below it is 2000x2000. Since the window size may be smaller, the image is scaled to the window size. Also I plan to add zoom feature, and therefore use scroll area.
Here is the code I have (I am using PyQt5, but I am pretty sure C++ Qt will work the same)
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

width, height = 2000, 2000
grid_step = 100

class MyWidget(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black")

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            print(f"Position: {event.pos()}")


class ImageApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, image_path=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = MyWidget()
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.label)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll_area)

        # Generate grid pixmap
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(width, height)
        self.pixmap.fill(Qt.black)
        painter = QPainter(self.pixmap)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.white, 1, Qt.SolidLine))
        for x in range(0, width, grid_step):
            painter.drawLine(x, 0, x, height)
        for y in range(0, height, grid_step):
            painter.drawLine(0, y, width, y)
        painter.end()

        self.resize(1000, 800)


    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        scaled_pixmap = self.pixmap.scaled(self.size().shrunkBy(QMargins(1, 1, 1, 1)),
                                            Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        self.label.setPixmap(scaled_pixmap)
        self.label.adjustSize()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ImageApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

The problem I faced is that coordinates in the mouse click handler are label widget coordinates. This is good for some tasks, such as drawing zoom-on lasso. But at the end of the day I need to get coordinates relative to the original 2000x2000 image. Perhaps I could calculate scale factor when resizing the image to the window, but this is only a part of the problem. The second part is that the window can be wider or narrower, and therefore letter-boxed to the image by adding top/bottom or left/right blank areas. Unfortunately I did not find a nice and easy way to calculate these blank areas, and translate window coordinates to image ones. Finally, when I add zoom feature and scroll bars, recalculation may get even harder.
So the question: is there a quick and nice, possibly Qt built-int way to recalculate between window and image coordinates?

"Perhaps I could calculate scale factor": that's exactly what you have to do. Basically: 1. get the position of the scaled image within the label; 2. map the cursor position (in label coordinates) by translating it by the top/left margins; 3. multiply that position by the inverse of the scaling ratio. Note that while doing basic image management is perfectly doable with QLabel, that class is generally not well suited for that purpose; it's common suggestion to use the Graphics View framework instead, which makes such computations much easier.

Also see graphics view related posts, such as this: Coordinates of an image PyQt
